# in CFileHelper findFiles by where file name = some name?

Tags: php, yii

i want to find only those files from some dir which equals to the names of the array from database.
in short, i have this code

```
$array = array(
    'img1.jpg','img2.jpg'
);
$array = serialize($array); 
$model->file=$array; 
$model->save();
// saved all the names in database and then:

$files = unserialize($model->file);
// and now, i have an array with the names:
Array
(
  [0] => img1.jpg
  [1] => img2.jpg
  [2] => img3.jpg
)
$path = 'files';
$data = CFileHelper::findFiles($path); // an array with files
```

and here i want to do something like; find $files from $data or echo files where $data file name = $files file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you use `scandir()`

```
$data = array('img1.gif','img2.gif'); // array of files from database
$files = scandir('/path/of/directory');
var_dump(array_intersect($data, $files));
```

Read [sacndir()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and [array_intersect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)